# Non-linear first order differential equation not separable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you please help with this non-linear first order DE
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y =\frac{x^2}{2} + x$$
Rearranged as below does not seem possible to separate variables so what now?
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2 + 2x}{4y} - 1$$

Regards - Ian

Comment: This is not research level question.  Exact solution methods most likely will not succeed here, but you should be able to get useful information from the phase portrait.  There are two singular points: a hyperbolic fixed point at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and a spiral source at $(x,y)=(-2,0)$.  You should be able to draw the separatrices and get a good idea of how the solutions behave, which should get you started on learning what you need to know about the solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Looks like I am out of my depth.

Comment: Maple code $ with(DEtools): odeadvisor(2*y(x)*(diff(y(x), x))+2*y(x) = (1/2)*x^2+x)$ produces $$[\_rational, [\_Abel, 2nd type, class A]]
 $$

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form solution, but as the comments mention, we can resort to direction fields to study the behavior of this system.

We see that there are some points interest, that are called fixed points, that is where the derivative is fixed at some point (for example, solve the RHS of your DEQ by setting it equal to zero).

A direction field plot produces:

[image]

If we add initial conditions, we see some strange behaviors because $y = 0$ is problematic, for example. Here are some initial conditions to clearly see how solutions behave (the phase lines tell you the direction field that the derivative takes).

[image]

Comment: Nice work, and great "illustrations"! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can have the following closed form solution but I do not know if it is useful for your purpose

> $$ x  =\sqrt [3]{-6\,y-6\,c-1+2\,\sqrt {-16\,{y}^{3}+9\,{
> c}^{2}+18\,cy-3\,{y}^{2}+3\,c}}-{\frac {-4\,y-1}{\sqrt [3]{-6\,y-6\,c-
> 1+2\,\sqrt {-16\,{y}^{3}+9\,{c}^{2}+18\,cy-3\,{y}^{2}+3\,c}}}}-1.$$

On the other hand, you can have an approximate solution using the power series techniques

> $$ y(x) = y_ 0  -x+\frac{1}{4y_0}\, {x}^{2}+\frac{1}{12}\,{\frac {y_ 0 +2}{
>  y_ 0^2}}{x}^{3}+O \left( {x}^{4}\right).$$

Comment: You may notice the clue of solving this ODE when you don't force to express the solution in terms of $x$ .

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}+2y=\dfrac{x^2}{2}+x$

$2y\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}+1\right)=\dfrac{x^2+2x}{2}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x(x+2)}{4y}-1$

Let $u=\dfrac{y}{x+2}$ ,

Then $y=(x+2)u$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(x+2)\dfrac{du}{dx}+u$

$\therefore(x+2)\dfrac{du}{dx}+u=\dfrac{x}{4u}-1$